# Extra baggage costs - Dragon Airlines / Cathay Pacific

Tags: india, china, hong-kong, fees-and-charges, cathay-pacific

I am traveling from Qingdao, China to Delhi, India via Hong Kong for business. My ticket itinerary has 1 piece of luggage confirmed. My flight details are as follows:

1. Qingdao - Hong Kong on Dragon Airlines
2. Hong Kong - Delhi on Cathay Pacific.

However, I bought some additional items that I have to take back with me (clothes and gift merchandise).

Now, I have an extra bag weighing 50 lbs (23 kg). I contacted my travel agency and they said that the cost of an extra bag is approximately 650 - 800 RMB. I searched various websites but have not found information to confirm this.

How can I positively confirm the price? And can I pay for an additional bag in advance to avoid any last-minute formalities?

Comment: Did you book with Cathay website or through a travel in agent? The price they quoted sounds reasonable. 1-2 kg is usually OK, and the check-in staff will probably just pass it. 23kg will be charged almost definitely. Even if the flight was book through an agent, you can check the status and make some amendments from Cathay web site by begs ring the confirmation number and last name of ticket holder

Answer (score 2):

Cathay/Dragon air free baggage allowance is **20KG** for Economic class, but my experience 2 weeks ago in Heathrow tells you can put not more than around **24KG**.

Cathay/Dragon extra bag charge is based on weight. It charges US$20 per KG from China(ZONE1) to Delhi(ZONE2), which means the extra bag costs you $460, around half of your ticket price